# How to know in Listbox which ListItem button is clicked?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, controltemplate, selectedindex

I have Listbox:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="FriendsRequestList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" Foreground="#FF316DCB"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RequestText}" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button Name="Accept" Content="Accept" Click="Accept_Click"  Foreground="#FF28901F" Background="#FFB4D8BA"/>
                                <Button Name="Decline" Content="Decline" Click="Decline_Click"  Foreground="#FF28901F" Background="#FFB4D8BA"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </Listbox>
```

And I try these in code:

```
  private void Accept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
        StackPanel st1 = clickedButton.Parent as StackPanel;
        StackPanel st2 = st1.Parent as StackPanel;
        StackPanel st3 = st2.Parent as StackPanel;
        object parentControl = st3.Parent;
        object obj = FriendsRequestList.Items[3];
        int index1 = FriendsRequestList.Items.IndexOf(obj);
        int index2 = FriendsRequestList.SelectedIndex; 
        int SenderId = FriendRequests.ElementAt(index).SenderID;
        UserServices.FriendRequestAccept(this, SenderId);
        UserServices.GetRequests(this);
    }
```

index2 is -1, and parentControl is null. Why ListItem.SelectedIndex is -1?
And how can I know which ListItem button is clicked ?

Comment: are you using Expression Blend 4?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ListBox.SelectedIndex` property is probably -1 because the `Button` is intercepting the click event and it is not being propagated to the `ListBox`. Anyway, you don't need the index to do what you're trying to do.

Let's say you set the `ItemsSource` as follows:

```
FriendsRequestList.ItemsSource = FriendRequests;
```

Now, assuming `FriendRequests` is some sort of collection containing `FriendRequest` objects, each of which contains the properties `FullName`, `RequestText` etc., modify the click handler to

```
private void Accept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FriendRequest req = ( sender as Button ).DataContext as FriendRequest;
  int senderID = req.SenderID;
  ...
}
```

Comment: FriendsRequestList.SelectedItem = clickedButton.DataContext;
 int index = FriendsRequestList.SelectedIndex;
int SenderId = FriendRequests.ElementAt(index).SenderID;

Comment: @AramGevorgyan That works too, but IMO it is wrong way to go about it. I don't understand why you can't just get `SenderID` from the button's DataContext instead of setting `ListBox.SelectedItem` and getting `ListBox.SelectedIndex`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I exactly set ListBox.SelectedItem and then get it SelectedIndex.

Comment: @AramGevorgyan Yes, but you don't need to mess with the ListBox at all. Look at the code I posted. `( sender as Button ).DataContext` *is the same as* the object you fetch using `FriendRequests.ElementAt(index)`. So, forget the ListBox completely, just cast the sender's DataContext and get `SenderID` from that.