# Make a clickable menu using longlist selector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to make a list of a menu and I want it to be clickable. When a user taps on it, it will change page (to another XAML). I am a beginner in Windows Phone programming, so, as now, I only use `selectionChanged`, but it only works for 1 string of the list.

So lets say I want to make a list of home, login, forum in the menu, I only could use `selectionChanged` for the first one.

I have searched for a solution over and over again on every site, but none of the sites share a full tutorial to make it.

If anybody knows how to make it, please help.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed multiple times on StackOverflow. What you're trying to achieve is to get some data associated with the LongListSelector's item been tapped. That data lives in the `DataContext` property of the item. When you handle the `Tap` event on the list item, you can retrieve your item's DataContext, cast it to required type, and use it as you wish, for example to navigate to some specific page, or whatever you want to achieve.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7728445/371804) answer as an exampe.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the templated application that are provided with the sdk.

Create a new project of type Databound App.